# Unable to set up DHCP and TFTP

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhcpd, tftp

I want to transfer my kernel image to beaglebone black, and the guide mentions that I should have already set up DHCP and tftp on the host machine.

I have set up the TFTP using:

```
sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa tftp-hpa
sudo vim /etc/default/tftpd-hpa 

TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="your-ftp-root-directory"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"

sudo service tftpd restart
```

Also I need a DHCP server on host so It can assign IP to BBBlack.

SO I followed:

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
sudo /etc/init.d/networking/restart
nano -w /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf


default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option routers 192.168.1.254;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
option domain-name "mydomain.example";

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
range 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.200;
} 


ls /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
```

INTERFACES "eth0":

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:ae:15:85:ae  
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:aeff:fe15:85ae/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:279343 (279.3 KB)
          Interrupt:16
```

/etc/network/interface

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        up service dhcp3-server restart
```

Yet. The DHCP is not getting setup.

Please suggest where I may be going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
# server-identifier 192.168.1.2;
ddns-update-style interim;
ignore client-updates;
authoritative;
default-lease-time 900;
max-lease-time 7200;
option ip-forwarding off;
option domain-name "mydomain.example";
option ntp-servers 0.pool.ntp.org, 1.pool.ntp.org, 2.pool.ntp.org, 3.pool.ntp.org;
shared-network mydomain {

    subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
         option routers 192.168.1.254;
         option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
         option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
         option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.2;
         option netbios-name-servers 192.168.1.2;
         range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
         range 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.200;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but afaik most of the devices that you can feed via tftp with new firmware need BOOTP to be enabled on their address that dhcpd provides to them.

Maybe this helps:

[BOOTP for client](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/dhcpd.8.html#contenttoc9) uses this example:

```
host haagen {
          hardware ethernet 08:00:2b:4c:59:23;
          fixed-address 239.252.197.9;
          filename "/tftpboot/haagen.boot";
        }
```

And regarding this:

```
TFTP_DIRECTORY="your-ftp-root-directory"
```

I guess you changed it to the actual directory?